# Move from Kubuntu 14.4 to Kubuntu 20.4

Tags: kubuntu

I am still running the (very old) Kubuntu 14.04 and want to upgrade to Kubuntu 20.04. I plan to do this by simply installing Kubuntu 20.04 into some new partitions (logical volumes to be precise), since I have new space and delete the old installation once I am done with moving.

What do I need to consider when moving? Especially, what directories should I take with me, which shouldn't I?

Is there a good strategy or are there best practices, where I should look for program files that I might want to keep?

Are there (official) moving guides out there?

Comment: there are no kubuntu releases named 14.4 or 20.4 I think you mean 14.04 and 20.04. that being said what you should take/copy is up to what you feel you need so maybe game save files pictures ect basically whatever you don't want to lose

Comment: @wraith3690001: Pictures etc. are all on external hard drives. I am talking about settings etc. of application programs. E.g. stuff in ~/.local - maybe?

Comment: @Nmath: I did not mean upgrade in the sense of directly upgrading. Maybe I have to rephrase the title. The first paragraph of my questions describes what I want to do.

Comment: @Make42 that would depend completely on what apps you have installed (and want to save) as some apps will save things in different locations as you have not specified any apps which you would like to save the settings of I can not tell you what to save.

Comment: In your case, I would *upgrade via re-install*.  ie. You can install a later release (or same release, even earlier release) of a system using the "Something-else", "Manual" or "Manual Partitioning" option, select your existing partitions, ensure you don't format any & install. It'll note your packages (ie. added software), erase system directories, install, try and add back your additional software IF available for new release then ask to reboot. It doesn't touch user files unless you formatted. Quick & easy; but backup first anyway (format box maybe missed etc).

Comment: Kubuntu 14.04 had two upgrade options, to next release 14.10 or the 2014-October release, or skip to the next LTS, ie. 16.04 LTS.  Kubuntu 16.04 LTS is now EOL too; as *flavors* have 3 years of supported life unlike main Ubuntu (desktop/server) which have 5 years. Official documentation on EOL upgrade is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades but note 14.04 being ESM may complicate things (some mirrors dropped it due EOL, others support ESM so you adjust for the mirror you were using; be it dropped or supported, main archive still supports it).

Comment: @guiverc if you read his post it clearly states he is planning to upgrade by installing kbuntu 20.04

Comment: Missed that (was hurried), no time now anyway (standup)